# Difference between a log scale and linear scale : np.random.rand()

Tags: deep-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, coursera

**How and why** will a linear `np.random.rand()`  (to generate a linear scale between 0.0001 and 1) **not** result in better distributed result but `np.power(10,-4 * np.random.rand())` (log scale) will. 
I am just accepting the below explanation as it is, But I can't understand the reason behind it.(simple math, i believe, which i am missing. Kindly help with some example)

---

Reference to my query:
**Using an Appropriate Scale to Pick Hyperparameters**

> To understand this, consider the number of hidden units
>   hyperparameter. The range we are interested in is from 50 to 100. We
>   can use a grid which contains values between 50 and 100 and use that
>   to find the best value:
>   [image]
>   
>   Now consider the learning rate with a range between 0.0001 and 1. If
>   we draw a number line with these extreme values and sample the values
>   uniformly at random, around **90% of the values will fall between 0.1 to
>   1**. In other words, we are using 90% resources to search between 0.1 to 1, and only 10% to search between 0.0001 to 0.1. This does not look
>   correct! Instead, **we can use a log scale** to choose the values:

[image]

This query is from Andrew Ng's Specialization Course on Deep Learning - Coursera 
Course 2 Week 3

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you want to do hyperparameteroptimization with a hyperparameter $h\in[0,1]$. Let us additionally assume that we want to test hundred possible values for the parameter.

If you choose a linear scale your parameter values will be uniformly selected form $[0,10^4]$. It will be very unlikely that you will small parameter values smaller than $10^{-4}$, because it is very unlikely to choose a number from this interval. The probability for randomly choosing a number from this interval is given by the following fraction

$$\dfrac{10^{-4}}{10^4}=10^{-8}.$$

Now if we choose our random numbers from the intervall $[-5,5]$ and use this as the power of the number $10$ we will stretch the interval onto an exponential scale which will make it more likely that we have numbers in $[0,10^{-4}]$ because the chance of choosing  a negative number for the exponent is much more likely. The probability will be $1/10$, because the wanted interval from $[-5,-4]$ has a width of $1$ and the whole interval from $[-5,5]$ has the width $10$.